Using multiple bounds constraints parameters for a convolved gaussian fit
I'm currently analyzing XRF spectra, specifically focusing on the spectrum of  (Pb). In XRF spectroscopy, the lines in the spectrum can often be effectively modeled by Gaussian distributions. Here, the mean value corresponds to the energy at which a photon emission occurs, while the amplitude can be thought of as a measure of the probability of that emission event.
The following code is aimed at fitting Gaussian functions to these spectrum lines. However, I'm encountering challenges in obtaining the standard deviation (sigma) of the Gaussian fit. Despite trying different initializations for sigma, the values remain the same. Interestingly, when using a similar initialization approach in another code, it works as expected.
Furthermore, I'm receiving a warning stating 'Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated'. My understanding is that this may be due to fixing too many variables for the fit, such as amplitude and mean value. One potential solution I considered was leaving the amplitude to be determined by the fitting process. However, I still want the amplitudes to adhere to specific probability relations defined here: peak_amplitudes = [1, 0.5996, 0.884*1, 0.884*0.51837].
Would anyone happen to have insights into how I could address these challenges?
Edit
By reading documentation about bounds, I thought that it was possible to fix the amplitude relations using that idea, but as you can see I have an error and I do not how to fix it.
The first part of the code is used to extract the data. And you can acces to it here  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oXTf4Ns60N6-JTI19vr_UKpvEM1qk31m/view?usp=sharing
Code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from google.colab import drive
import os
# Mount Google Drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')


# Function to read numeric data from a file
def read_numeric_data(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='latin1') as f:
        data = []
        live_time = None
        real_time = None
        for line in f:
            if 'LIVE_TIME' in line:
                live_time = line.strip()
            elif 'REAL_TIME' in line:
                real_time = line.strip()
            elif all(char.isdigit() or char in ".-+e" for char in line.strip()):
                row = [float(x) for x in line.split()]
                data.extend(row)
    return np.array(data), live_time, real_time

file_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/ProjetoXRF_Manuel/April2024/20240402_Pb.mca'
data, _, _ = read_numeric_data(file_path)

a = -0.0188026396003431
b = 0.039549044037714
Data = data
dim = 0


# Función para convolucionar múltiples gaussianas
def multi_gaussian(x, *params):
    eps = 1e-10
    y = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i in range(0, len(params), 3):
        amplitude, mean, sigma = params[i:i+3]
        y += amplitude * np.exp(-(x - mean)**2 / (2 * sigma**2 + eps))
    return y

sigma=[]
area=[]
# Función para graficar el espectro de energía convolucionado
def plot_convolved_spectrum(Data, a, b,i, ax=None):
    maxim = np.max(Data)
    workingarray = np.squeeze(Data)

    # Definir puntos máximos
    peaks, _ = find_peaks(workingarray / maxim, height=0.1)
    peak_values = workingarray[peaks] / maxim
    peak_indices = peaks

    # Calcular valores de energía correspondientes a los picos
    energy_spectrum = a + b * peak_indices

    # Preparar datos para convolución
    data = workingarray[:885] / maxim
    data_y = data / data.max()
    data_x = a + b * np.linspace(0, 885, num=len(data_y))

    # Ajustar múltiples gaussianas al espectro de energía
    peak_indices2, _ = find_peaks(data_y, height=0.1)
    peak_amplitudes = data_y[peak_indices2]
    peak_means = data_x[peak_indices2]
    print("means",peak_means)
    print("amplitudes",peak_amplitudes)
    peak_sigmas = [0.1] * 4

    params_init = list(zip(peak_amplitudes, peak_means, peak_sigmas))
    params_init = np.concatenate(params_init)


    # Ajustar curva

    # BOUNDS
    lower_bound_1=1
    upper_bound_1=lower_bound_1
    ###########################
    lower_bound_2=0.5996
    upper_bound_2=lower_bound_2
    ###########################
    lower_bound_3=0.884
    upper_bound_3=lower_bound_3
    ###########################
    lower_bound_4=0.51837
    upper_bound_4=lower_bound_4
    # Define bounds for each amplitude individually
    amplitude_bounds = [[(lower_bound_1, upper_bound_1)],[(lower_bound_2, upper_bound_2)],[(lower_bound_3, upper_bound_3)],[(lower_bound_4, upper_bound_4)]]

    # Ensure that the number of bounds matches the number of amplitude parameters
    assert len(amplitude_bounds) == 4, "Number of bounds should match the number of amplitude parameters"

    # Define bounds for each parameter individually
    #amplitude_bounds = [(lower_bound_1, upper_bound_1), (lower_bound_2, upper_bound_2), (lower_bound_3, upper_bound_3), (lower_bound_4, upper_bound_4)]
    mean_bounds = [(-np.inf, np.inf)] * 4
    sigma_bounds = [(0, np.inf)] * 4

    # Combine bounds for all parameters
    bounds = amplitude_bounds + mean_bounds + sigma_bounds
    # Ensure that the bounds are properly structured as tuples
    #bounds = tuple(bounds)
    #print("forma",np.shape(bounds))
    # Ajustar curva con bounds específicos para cada amplitud
    params, params_cov = curve_fit(multi_gaussian, data_x, data_y, p0=params_init, bounds=bounds)



    # Obtener una interpolación de alta resolución del ajuste
    x_fine = np.linspace(data_x.min(), data_x.max(), num=20000)
    y_fit = multi_gaussian(x_fine, *params)

    # Gráfico
    ax.scatter(data_x, data_y, color='black', marker='o', s=20)
    ax.plot(x_fine, y_fit, label="Fit", linewidth=1.5)

    # Anotar picos con etiquetas de energía
    for i in range(len(peak_indices)):
        ax.annotate(f"{energy_spectrum[i]:.2f} KeV", (data_x[peak_indices2[i]], data_y[peak_indices2[i]]),
                     textcoords="offset points", xytext=(0, 10), ha='center')

    # Extraer desviaciones estándar y amplitudes
    sigmas_array = params[2::3]
    amplitudes_array = params[::3]

    # Calcular áreas bajo las curvas gaussianas
    areas = [amplitudes_array[i] * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * sigmas_array[i] for i in range(len(sigmas_array))]
    area.append(areas)
    total_area = np.sum(areas)

    # Calcular sigma promedio
    sigma.append(np.mean(sigmas_array))

    # Configuración del gráfico
    ax.set_xlabel('Energy (KeV)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Normalized Data')
    ax.legend()
    ax.set_title('Convolved Energy Spectrum')

    # Imprimir información
    print("Standard deviations:", sigmas_array)
    print("Amplitudes:", amplitudes_array)
    print("Areas:", areas)





if dim == 0:

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plot_convolved_spectrum(Data, a, b,1,ax=ax)
    ax.set_xlim(9, 15)
    plt.show()
else:

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for i in range(Data.shape[1]):
        plot_convolved_spectrum(Data[:,i], a, b,i, ax=ax)  # Pass the ax object to plot_energy_spectrum
    ax.set_xlim([np.min(inf),np.max(sup)])
    plt.show()

Edit
This is the error that I obtained

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_lsq/least_squares.py in
prepare_bounds(bounds, n)
94
95 def prepare_bounds(bounds, n):
---> 96     lb, ub = (np.asarray(b, dtype=float) for b in bounds)
97     if lb.ndim == 0:
98         lb = np.resize(lb, n)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)


I have to admit that I did not understand from your description what it is you want to do. It's also not clear to me whether what you have actually works, or does not (and in that case what it is you expect and what it is you get).

Apologies for the confusion. Let me clarify and see if this explanation is more helpful.
Firstly, I aim for a specific adjustment after my data is fitted: ensuring that the amplitudes are not arbitrary. By "not arbitrary," I mean to establish a deliberate relationship between the amplitudes of the Gaussian distributions involved. For instance, I intend for the amplitude of the second Gaussian to be precisely half that of the first Gaussian. Additionally, I desire a specific ratio between the amplitudes of the third and fourth Gaussians, such as 3:4.

Additionally, concerning the current state of affairs: it appears that the system is not functioning as intended. As depicted in the plot, when allowing the Gaussian fit to proceed without constraints, it yields negative amplitudes. Moreover, these amplitudes do not adhere to the desired relationships. Furthermore, there are instances where the standard deviations are negative, which is also contrary to expectations.

And all of this happens (the negative standar deviations and amplitudes) because I fixed the mean values, and I did that because is information that iIknow.

OK, so now I know what it is you want to do. And that the result doesn't match your expectations. But I don't know how you do it, and that is apparently where the problem then is. I think you should edit your post explaining but what you describe in comments above, and in particular which algorithm/method you use to obtain the fit.

Okey i would do that. I think that now is better

let me know if know it is better

Well, fixing the python error would be a good starting point to get a working algorithm.
